# How to keep a key and the associated value from interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the code below, how could one assert in `func` that the parameter `type` is `Enum1[]` if `key === 'enum1'` or `Enum2[]` if `key === 'enum2'`?

```js
enum Enum1 {
  ENUM_1_KEY_1 = 'ENUM_1_KEY_1',
  ENUM_1_KEY_2 = 'ENUM_1_KEY_2',
}

enum Enum2 {
  ENUM_2_KEY_1 = 'ENUM_2_KEY_1',
  ENUM_2_KEY_2 = 'ENUM_2_KEY_2',
}

interface EnumNamespace {
  enum1: Enum1[]
  enum2: Enum2[]
}

function func<K extends keyof EnumNamespace>(key: K, type: EnumNamespace[K]) {
  log(type) // -> (parameter) type: Enum1[] | Enum2[]
}
```

Comment: but you already did it. also you did not share `log` implementation

Comment: `log` was just for showing the type output, sorry for the brevity. The thing is; I'm using the `key` and `type` to construct a template string inside `func`. However, TS complains because the values of `Enum2[]` doesn't map to `enum1` and vice versa. Is there a way to assert that there is strictly a key-value relationship inside `func` or am I just sort of wrong here?

Comment: I did post another question with a use case for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476828/how-to-map-enum-values-to-their-respective-keys-in-typescript.

Comment: There is nothing more the compiler can infer here without adding conditionals within the function. Also, questions should be self-contained, so you should explain what the function should achieve/provide a simplified implementation.

Comment: Is it acceptable to change `func` parameters to union type?
`function func({key, type}: { key: "enum1"; type: Enum1[] } | { key: "enum2"; type: Enum2[] }) {};`